# Call either of two different functions based on a variable

Tags: python

I have two different functions `cd_0` and `cd_90` which return a floating point variable. I am using `curve_fit` function in which I call either one of these function. I want to call either one of these functions using an `var` value (`cd_<var>`) which can be either 0 or 90. The `var` value is known at the beginning of the program and does not get modified. This being the case, I do not want to introduce a `if` check since it will slow down the optimization function calling these either of two functions. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd_func = cd_0 if var == 0 else cd_90
```

Later, when you want to call the chosen function:

```
my_float = cd_func()
```

Note that a dict will also solve the problem, but you still make a check on every reference.  It's faster than your original `if`, but slower than the direct reference of `cd_func`.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose `a` and `b` are the variables for `cd_0` and `cd_90` i.e `cd_0(a,b)` and `cd_90(a,b)`. Then I have to just use `cd_func(a,b)`?

Comment: `my_float = cd_func()` You forgot the parentheses

Comment: Right: call with the appropriate arguments.  @JohnGordon, thanks for catching the typo.

Answer (score 1):

While not too elegant, you can actually use a dictionary for this.

```
methods = {'cd_0': cd_0, 'cd_90', cd_90}

method_name = f'cd_{var}' # use f-strings since you know var

# to call
methods[method_name]()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to this that you can try, I will list some that are on the top of my head and choose what suits you.

1. Using python's `eval` function.

Python's `eval` would run a `string` as **Python** syntax. Example:
`eval("cd_{}({})".format(val, param))` which would translate to running `cd_90(param)` if `var` is `90`.

2. Using pointers to functions with an if statement.

`func = cd_90 if var else cd_0`

then now `func` is now a substitute for `cd_90` or `cd_0`

I would advise using the 2nd solution as you don't want to call functions using `eval` for security concerns.

3. Assigning the functions to values of a `dict` object, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66843731/1961688) answer.